# why is my keras custom metric not working?

Tags: keras, metrics, loss

Why does this code work fine for the loss function but the metrics fail after one iteration with "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,) (24,) (32,)"?

If I use "categorical_crossentropy" in quotes then it works. And my custom metric looks identical to the one in keras.losses.

```
import keras.backend as K
def categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)

fc.compile(optimizer=Adam(.01), loss=categorical_crossentropy, metrics=[categorical_crossentropy])
fc.fit(xtrain, ytrain, validation_data=(xvalid, yvalid), verbose=0,
       callbacks=[TQDMNotebookCallback(leave_inner=True, leave_outer=True)],
       nb_epoch=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if I import categorical_crossentropy from keras.metrics; rather than importing K. Still no idea why the above doesn't work but at least this is a solution.

Also it looks like the loss function is not necessary in metrics parameter anyway as it is automatically calculated and shown for training and validation.